# Maximum number of legal moves after n moves in a chess game

Tags: chess, optimization

Given the chess start position :

[image]

What is the maximum number of legal moves **white** can play after **$n$** full moves? 
*We will assume black is helping white in this task.*

I want the best answer you could find with $n$ varying from 2 to 20 (too high and it becomes too long to solve, too low and it will be trivial). Since I do not know the answer for high values of $n$, your goal is to produce the 'most perfect' answer. The 'score' of an answer will be calculated by adding the number of moves for each value of $n$.

*I know the answers for n=0 to 4. Computing the answer for low values of n is trivial, but becomes almost impossible for high values.*

For clarification, here are the answers for $n=0$ and $n=1$:

$n=0$:

> 20 moves (16 pawn moves and 4 knight moves)

$n=1$:

> 31 moves after 1.e4 d5 or 1..f5 (16 pawn, 5 knights, 5 bishops, 4 queen, 1 king)

Remember: you do **not** have to find the perfect solution. The accepted answer will be the overall best if no improvements are found for a long period of time. **Computers are allowed**. *Good luck!*

Comment: Just to clarify: can the first $n$ moves of the solution for $n+1$ be different from the moves of the solution for $n$?

Comment: Yes. The intended answer is 19 variations of length 2-20 full move. The 19 variations are independent from each other. Otherwise it would be too easy to compute ( you are still encouraged to compute it anyways, as it can be used to determine the lower bound for each value of n).

Comment: "the answer with the highest overall number of legal moves will be marked as accepted after ~1 week" -- This does not appear to be a puzzle then, but a game that people compete in. This question seems to me to be off-topic.

Comment: Because it is impossible to compute and verify what is the perfect answer, I had to set an arbitrary timer. It can be removed if it bothers you. What I meant is, the 'most perfect' answer will be chosen after 1 week. I'll remove the 1 week delay, but I think optimization questions with an unknown perfect answer are within the rules. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is near exactly the type of question that [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) was meant to rule out. In my eyes, it's not a puzzle, because it isn't designed to have a solution -- it's a question you're interested in, but there's no point at which you can say it's definitively *solved*.

Comment: So I've closed this question as off-topic: since answers can be arbitrarily extended and there's no point at which we've reached a definitive solution, the question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 7):

I found

> [OEIS sequence A278830 'Maximal number of possible moves at the n-th ply of a chess game'](http://oeis.org/A278830)
>  whose entries are: **20**, 20, **31**, 32, **46**, 48, **52**, 55, **61**, 63
>  The bold entries correspond to the positions where White is to move, so those are your answers for $n = 0$ to $4$.

Comment: Yes, these were my answers for 0-4. After 5 it becomes really long to compute. This is where the real challenge starts.